# Firebase FCM - React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

Well, I'm new to React Native and Firebase and I have some questions about it. If somebody could help me I would appreciate it!

1. How react-native-fcm is related to Firebase Notifications Console? Is there a configuration on fcm when implementing that refers to that "notification database"?
2. On react-native-fcm documentation there's an example that uses:

   `FCM.subscribeToTopic('/topics/foo-bar');`

   Is that a reference to Firebase or something? Or it's just a silly question?
3. There's any way to send a notification when a child is added to Firebase Database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. react-native-fcm I think is a React library to use FCM. Firebase Notifications Console is a part of the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) where you're able to send push notifications towards your app without the use of your own App Server.
2. It's a function for sendig messages to [Topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging).
3. There is. The recently released [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) sounds like what you're looking for. Specifically, [Realtime Database Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). :)

Comment: P.S. Although your post is not that broad, it would be advisable to have one question per post. Cheers! :)

Comment: I'm sorry! Thank you so much, I will look up the cloud functions, I think it's what I need :)

Comment: You're welcome Rafael. :) If you think this post answered your questions sufficiently, you could mark it as correct by clicking on the Check Mark at the left side of the post. Cheers! :)